# JQuery selector on DataTable works only after alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following (simplified) JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#bot_table').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "/static/Dashboard/pos.txt",
        "paging":   false,
        "searching": false,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name_of_instance"},
            { "data": "bt" },
            { "data": "updated" },
            { "data": "pos" },
            { "data": "l_s" },
            { "data": "l_t" },
            { "data": "p_l" },
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            }
        ],
    } );


 $("td").html(function(){
    var elem =  $(this).html().replace("DELETE INSTANCE", "<button id = \"gen_del_instance\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span> <u>DELETE INSTANCE</u></button>")
    return elem
});
```

The thinking is that once the `DataTable` is loaded the selector below will find any instances of a string and replace it with a button.

This doesn't work, though. It only works if I precede an `alert()` before the `$("td")`etc. selector.

My understanding is that the `DOM` is not updated after the `DataTable()` call and is forcibly updated after the `alert()`.

Is there any way to achieve my wanted behavior?

Comment: should do that in a rendering callback on the column. The delay is because the data is loaded asynchronously using ajax so none of the `<td>` are populated yet when you try to replace content

Comment: can you please further explain this, or provide a similar source/way to do that?

Comment: https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
var table = $('#bot_table').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "/static/Dashboard/positions.txt",
        "paging":   false,
        "searching": false,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name_of_instance",
               "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                var new_data = data.replace("DELETE INSTANCE", "<button id = \"gen_del_instance\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span> <u>DELETE INSTANCE</u></button>");
                return new_data;
            }},
            { "data": "bot" },
            { "data": "updated" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "l_s" },
            { "data": "l_t" },
            { "data": "p_l" },
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            }
        ],
    } );
```

Thanks @charlietfl